# How to make a Preference not save to SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preference, listpreference

I am re-using ListPreference for a setting which I store only in the database. How can I prevent it from storing/persisting any data to the preference file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass it, override `shouldPersist()` to return false.

Comment: This will work, but the proper way is to simply call `setPersistent(false)`. Documentation for this method is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setPersistent(boolean)).

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it myself, but have you looked into overriding `onDialogClosed()`?